# Chromatic Polynomial for a Graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

I have

[image]

The [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial) for this is given as
$P(G_e,\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)^3$.

[image]

How is this calculated?

Answer (score 3):

Say you have $\lambda$ colors available. You can use any of the $\lambda$ colors to color $b$. You can use any color to color $a$, except the one you used to color $b$, so $\lambda-1$ choices for $a$. Similarly, $\lambda-1$ choices for $c$, and then $\lambda-1$ choices for $d$. All up, $\lambda(\lambda-1)^3$.

Comment: You could start at $a$ and get the same result

Comment: @Henry, yes, for this graph, or for any tree (or forest), you could start anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For a tree with $n$ vertices, you can use [deletion-contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Deletion.E2.80.93contraction) inductively to show the chromatic polynomial is $\lambda(\lambda-1)^{n-1}$

So taking your example and considering deleting the edge $cd$ and contracting $c$ and $d$, you would get $P(G_4,\lambda) = P(G_3,\lambda) P(G_1,\lambda) -P(G_3,\lambda)$ so knowing $P(G_3,\lambda)=\lambda(\lambda-1)^{2}$ and $P(G_1,\lambda)=\lambda$ gives the result.